# Не получается исправить ошибку "Error trying to diff"

Tags: angular4, angular5

Есть компонента:
html:

```
<div class="text-center align-middle">
  <div *ngIf="src !== null">
    <img style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px;" src="{{src}}" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input style="display:none;" type="file" (change)="onChangeFile($event)" #file>
    <button *ngIf="changed" (click)="file.click()">Выбрать изображение</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-load-img-ox',
  templateUrl: './load-img-ox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./load-img-ox.component.less']
})
export class LoadImgOxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() private changed:boolean = false;
  public image = null;
  @Input() public src = null;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onChangeFile(event) {
    this.image = <File>event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      this.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.image);
  }
}
```

использую:

```
<table class="table table-inverse">
  <tr class="text-center">
    <th>Название</th>
    <th>Описание</th>
    <th>Изображение</th>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><app-load-img-ox [changed]='true'></app-load-img-ox></td>
    <td><button>добавить</button></td>
    <td><button>очистить</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let c of Categories;" [(ngModel)]="this.Categories" ngDefaultControl>
    <td>{{c.title}}</td>
    <td>{{c.discription}}</td>
    <td><app-load-img-ox [src]=c.image [changed]='true'></app-load-img-ox></td>
    <td><button>изменить</button></td>
    <td><button>удалить</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button (click)="test2()">TEST</button>
```

Итог:

Отображение в порядке (консоль без ошибок).
При попытки выбора изображение в консоли ошибка:

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'C:\fakepath\btn-rigtn-active.png'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:19041)
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3190)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22004)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23265)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23227)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23861)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23821)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdminPanelCrudGroupComponent.html:16)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23813)
    at checkAndUpdateView
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как исправить, и если возможно объясните причину ошибки. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что такое `Categories`? эта ошибка возникает если пытаться итерировать не массив, я вижу что у вас какая-то каша с `*ngFor="let c of Categories" [(ngModel)]="this.Categories"`

Comment: @overthesanity `[{"id": 10,"title": "Чтото", "discription": "Ничег", "image": "https://localhost:44311/ProductImages/55.png"},{.....},{...}]` - в общем полученные данные с api